# QT openCV frame display

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I want to use openCV to capture photos.

I use two labels for showing,one is for video stream and the other is for the captured photo.

Now the captured photo is works well,but the video stream cannot be display and always got a segmentation fault!

Actually,both of the codes almost exactly the same：

```
void CameraCap::on_CapBtn_clicked()
{
  frame = cvQueryFrame(cam);
  QImage image = QImage((const uchar*)frame->imageData, frame->width, \ 
                 frame->height, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
  ui->pictureLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}



void CameraCap::readFrame()
{
  frame = cvQueryFrame(cam);
  QImage image = QImage((const uchar*)frame->imageData, frame->width, \ 
                 frame->height, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
  ui->videoLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}

void CameraCap::on_openBtn_clicked()
{
  cam = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
  timer->start(33);
}

timer   = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(readFrame()));
```

That is to say, the function of on_CapBtn_clicked() works well,but the function readFrame() always leads to segmentation fault!

Why does this happen?